# Paging for facets in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am getting the facets for a give search string using

```
search:search($q, $options)
```

Where `$q is the search text`
and `$options` is

```
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <constraint name="kn_entry_number">
    <range type="xs:string" facet="true">
      <facet-option>frequency-order</facet-option>
      <facet-option>descending</facet-option>
      <facet-option>limit=5</facet-option>
      <facet-option>skip=3</facet-option>
      <field name="kn_entrynumber">
      </field>
    </range>
  </constraint>
  <return-results>false</return-results>
  <return-facets>true</return-facets>
</options>
```

I want to get the top 5 after the top 3, so as to mimic the paging. But `skip` option does not seem to work here.

Is there any way of doing this using the search api, or my only option is to use `cts queries`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to page over the values in a range index, you could also take a look at `search:values()`:

http://docs.marklogic.com/search:values

You would have to use `search:search()` to parse the query.

Alternatively, you could use `cts:parse()` -- which takes a somewhat different approach to parsing query text -- and `cts:values()` or `cts:value-ranges()`

Hoping that helps,